# UseHistory push changes url but not the site

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I use react router dom in V5.

This is my router:

```
 <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/loggedIn">
        <LoggedInLandingPage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/">
        <LandingPage />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

This is my code in my Register Page:

```
 const register = () => {
    Axios.post("registration", state)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        try
        {
            setCookie("user", response.data);
            history.push("/loggedIn");
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    })
}
```

So the URL changed, e.g. from [www.domain.com/register](http://www.domain.com/register) to [www.domain.com/loggedIn](http://www.domain.com/loggedIn) but the website didnt change / refresh. When I now hit F5 everything is fine.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: could you try adding the exact keyword on the route with path="/" like <Route exact path="/" ...

Comment: @Eric No, because I have subroutes in there, this would change all subroute behaviour

Comment: @Unknown Thank you, that seems to be right, I will look into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 <Router>
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage}/>
       <Route path="/loggedIn" component={LoggedInLandingPage}>
    </Switch>
 </Router>
```

Comment: If I would do that, the <LandingPage /> wouldn't be the default landing page any more e.g. there is a wrong URL or something like that

Comment: worst case scenario is to use windows location href.

Comment: Well, if that would be the case, why is useHistory then build :D

Answer (score 1):

try

```
yarn add history@4.7.0
```

or

```
npm install history@4.7.0
```

Comment: Done, no change.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem I found out that there was two Embedded <Router tag, maybe one is in parent component or app.js file, check this